# LDAP AUTHENTICATION via vb.net not working

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to authenticate users via LDAP.

I am able to query ldap and fill a listbox with users found in a certain OU.

When i try to authenticate via a user found in the above list, it returns my msgbox of "Failed to Login".

Here is my code:

This is put in a button function

```
Dim uid As String = txtusername.Text & ",OU=fake,OU=fake,DC=fake,DC=com"
Dim password As String = txtpassword.Text
Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://fake.com/OU=fake,OU=fake,DC=fake,DC=com", uid, password, AuthenticationTypes.None)

Try
    Dim ds As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(de)
    ds.FindOne()
    MsgBox("Login!")
Catch
    MsgBox("Fail!")
End Try
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the DirectoryEntry constructor overloads allows you to specify the username and password. To see if the user name and password are correct try and create a directoryEntry object with the given username and password. If the password username combination are incorrect you will get an exception. Here is a sample function to authenicate a user.

```
 Public Function Authenicate(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean
       Dim isValid As Boolean = False
    Try
       Dim de As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://YourActiveDirectoryName", username, password, _
                DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure Or _
                DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Sealing Or _
                DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Signing)
        de.RefreshCache()
        isValid = True
    Catch
    End Try
    Return isValid
End Function
```

Comment: thanks ken. how can i call that function in a button using my txtusername and txtpassword boxes?

Comment: Try something like if Authenicate(txtUserName.Text,txtPassword.Text) then MsgBox("Login") else MsgBox("Fail") end if